# Setting package_dir to ..?

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools, distribute

I have a Git repository cloned into `myproject`, with an `__init__.py` at the root of the repository, making the whole thing an importable Python package.

I'm trying to write a setuptools `setup.py` for the package, which will also sit in the root of the repository, next to the `__init__.py` file. I want `setup.py` to **install the directory it resides in** as a package. It's fine if setup.py itself comes along as part of the installation, but it would be better if it didn't. Ideally this should work also in editable mode (`pip install -e .`)

Is this configuration at all supported? I can kind of make it work by having a `package_dir= {"": ".."},` argument to `setup()`, telling it to look for `myproject` in the directory above the current one. However, this requires the package to always be installed from a directory named `myproject`, which does not appear to be the case if, say, it's being installed through `pip`, or if someone is working out of a Git clone named `myproject-dev`, or in any number of other cases.

Another hack I'm contemplating is a symlink to `.` named `mypackage` inside of the repository. That ought to work, but I wanted to check if there was a better way first.

Answer (score 8):

See also [Create editable package setup.py in the same root folder as __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58375315/11138259)

As far as I know this should work:

```
myproject-dev/
├── __init__.py
├── setup.py
└── submodule
    └── __init__.py
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    name='MyProject',
    version='0.0.0.dev0',
    packages=['myproject', 'myproject.submodule'],
    package_dir={
        'myproject': '.',
    },
)
```

---

One way to make this work for *editable* or *develop* installations is to manually modify the `easy-install.pth` file.

Assuming:

- the project lives in: `/home/user/workspace/empty/project`;
- a virtual environment `.venv` is used;
- the project is installed with `python3 -m pip install -e .` or `python3 setup.py develop`;
- the Python version is 3.6.

Then:

- the file is found at a location such as `/home/user/workspace/empty/project/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/easy-install.pth`;
- its content is: `/home/user/workspace/empty/project`.

In order to let the imports work as expected one can edit this line to read the following:

- `/home/user/workspace/empty`

Note:

- Everything in `/home/user/workspace/empty` that looks like a Python package is then susceptible to be imported, that is why it is a good idea to place the project in its own directory, in this case the directory `empty` contains nothing else but the directory `project`.
- The module `project.setup` is also importable.