# Create editable package setup.py in the same root folder as __init__.py

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

An existing project is setup in a way that the repository has an `__init__.py` in at the root folder. I would like to create a `setup.py` in the repository so this would be the resulting project structure:

```
project-master/
├── __init__.py
├── setup.py
└── submodule1
    ├── code.py
    └── __init__.py
└── submodule2
    ├── code.py
    └── __init__.py
```

and you should be able to:

```
git clone project.url
cd project-master
pip install -e .
from project.submodule1 import ...
```

I tried the hacky solution of temporarily copying the contents in a subfolder so that `setup.py` is one level up from the package folder and installing from there. This works well if I `pip install .` but unfortunately this solution doesn't work in editable mode because I delete the temporary folder after installing.

**Question**: What is the right way to create a proper `setup.py` that works in editable mode and lives in the same root folder as the package's `__init__.py`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible to install such a project as editable.

Comment: @sinoroc, yep I am reaching the same conclusion. One of the main issues lies in the dash in the project name.

Comment: In the domain of Python packaging, you can sometimes use the underscore `_` instead of the dash `-`.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to be possible for an *editable* installation. As far as I know the closest one can get is as following:

```
project-master/
├── __init__.py
├── setup.py
└── submodule1
    └── __init__.py
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    name='ProjectMaster',
    version='0.0.0.dev0',
    packages=['project', 'project.submodule'],
    package_dir={
        'project': '.',
        'project.submodule': './submodule1',
    },
)
```

---

**Update**

See the following for an idea how to use such a project in *editable* or *develop* mode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58429242/11138259