# Python setuptools: packaging the root directory (no subdirectory per package wanted)

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I need to write a package into a repository, but it is a small quick package, so I don't see the need to put files into a subdirectory. I simply want:

```py
import mypkg.module1
```

with directory structure

```
root_folder/
    - setup.py
    - __init__.py  # the init for package "mypkg" (empty)
    - module1.py
```

And I don't want to be *constrained* to increase the folder hierarchy like here:

```py
root_folder/
    - setup.py
    - mypkg/  # WHY would I do that for 1 module??
        - __init__.py
        - module1.py
```

```py
# Content of setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='MyPkg',
      packages=['mypkg']
      package_dir={'mypkg': '.'})
```

but as a result, `import mypkg` fails, and `import module1` works, instead of the desired `import mypkg.module1`.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/812242/4614641), but the answer of "just move setup.py one folder up" does not suit me.

After finding setup argument documentation [here](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html), I tried to define a namespace package:

```py
# Content of setup.py with a namespace package
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='MyPkg',
      packages=['thisdir']
      package_dir={'thisdir': '.'},
      namespace_packages=['mypkg'])
```

Comment: Maybe this will put you on the right track: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58429219 -- Namespace is most likely not what you want. -- You might be interested in looking into `py_modules` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without testing, I think maybe something like that could work:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    name='MyPkg',
    version='0.0.0.dev0',
    packages=['mypkg'],
    package_dir={
        'mypkg': '.',
    },
)
```

The biggest issue is that, as far as I remember, you will end up with `setup.py` in the package `mypkg` as well, so that `import mypkg.setup` will indeed import the `setup` module. I have not verified.

The other big issue is that, as with most of the `package_dir` modifications, the "develop/editable" installation will most likely not work at all.

---

> but as a result, `import mypkg` fails, and `import module1` works, instead of the desired `import mypkg.module1`

I could imagine this happening, if the project is not actually installed, and the current working directory is the project's root directory.

For `import mypkg` to succeed you have to make sure the project is correctly installed (`python -m pip install .`).

And for `import module1` to fail, you might need to change to a different directory.

---

***Related***:

- [Create editable package setup.py in the same root folder as __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58375315/create-editable-package-setup-py-in-the-same-root-folder-as-init-py)
- [Setting package_dir to ..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756742/setting-package-dir-to)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to go to another directory before testing...
The command I use to install is `python3 setup.py develop --user -N`. I'll check what you propose. Good point about importing setup, thank you.

Comment: You really shoud use `python -m pip install --editable .` (instead of `setup.py develop`). -- And also this will not work with editable/develop installation anyway, you can forget about it. I expanded on this in one of the linked related questions.