# Packaging python project with pyproject.toml file in the package folder

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

Let's assume I wrote a python package with the following structure:

```
├── package_name
│   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── file_name.py
│   ├── pyproject.toml
```

Then, I would want to build against the toml file so that when I install the package, I can do

```
from package_name.file_name import some_function
```

I look at the setuptools [documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html), seems it should be feasible with package_dir.
I tried:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "package_name"
version = "0.0.1"
    
[tool.setuptools.package-dir]
rads_pyspark_utils = "../package_name"

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["package_name"]
```

But when I run a `python -m build` files are not added to the wheel, it just has the metadata information.

Comment: You can probably adjust this answer to your specific needs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58429242